# updating files using nodejs with 1 button

Tags: html, node.js

I've wrote an example to upload a file using nodejs based on tutorials found online, here's what I have now :

**`index.html`**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Simple Multer Upload Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="file-to-upload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>  
  </body>
</html>
```

and the `app.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path')

// init app 
const app = express();
// set storage

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: 'uploads',
  filename: function(req,file,cb){
    cb(null,'MYONE'+path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
}
)

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// It's very crucial that the file name matches the name attribute in your html
app.post('/', upload.single('file-to-upload'), (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

my question is, is there a way to merge both buttons in one `select/upload?` 
thanks in advance for any hint !

Comment: Can you be more specific ? You want the `select/upload` button in html at a same time ?

Comment: instead of having two button one to upload the file and the second to upload it. having one button that does both ?